# Typescript: Property does not exist

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I'm trying to develop a decorator for REST Api Interfaces in Typescript. Here it is the decorator implementation

```
export function RemoteResource(params: any): Function {
    console.log("RemoteResource.params: ", params);
    return function (target: Function) {

        //--POST
        target.prototype.post = function () {
            console.log("----POST");
        };

        //--GET
        target.prototype.retrieve = function () {
            console.log("----GET");
        };

        //--DELETE
        target.prototype.remove = function () {
            console.log("----DELETE");
        };

        //--PULL
        target.prototype.update = function () {
            console.log("----PULL");
        };

        console.log("RemoteResource.target: ", target);

        return target;
    }
}
```

Now, I can use the decorator `@RemoteResource` and the methods `post|retrieve|remove|update` are added to the original object prototype correctly.

```
@RemoteResource({
    path: "/foos",
    methods: [],
    requireAuth: false
})
export class Foo { }
```

From here, if I execute

```
let tester = new Foo();
tester.post() //--This prints out "----POST" correctly
```

I've the log printed out correctly, but I've also have the following error: "Property 'post' does not exist on type 'Foo'."
While I understand why I'm having this error (Foo doesn't have any declared `post` property) I'm not sure about how to fix it.

Ideally, I would like that the TS compiler understand that the decorator extends the original object adding up those methods.

How can I achieve it? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see this library? (https://github.com/thiagobustamante/typescript-rest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are adding these methods dynamically at runtime in the decorator, the compiler has no way of knowing that these methods will exist for `Foo` instances.

You can change that in different ways, for example:

(1) Using an interface and intersection:

```
interface RemoteResource {
    post(): void;
    remove(): void;
    update(): void;
    retrieve(): void;
}

let tester = new Foo() as Foo & RemoteResource;
tester.post(); // no error
```

(2) Interface and empty methods:

```
export class Foo implements RemoteResource {
    post: () => void;
    remove: () => void;
    update: () => void;
    retrieve: () => void;
}

let tester = new Foo() as Foo & RemoteResource;
tester.post();
```

---

#### Edit

@Robba suggests:

(3) Ignore all type checking

```
let tester = new Foo() as any;
tester.post();
```

or

```
let tester = new Foo();
tester["post"]();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At the end I reworked the decorator into an interface and then implemented it using a class.